# OpenGl Terrain mesh into gaussian blob

Tags: opengl, glut, terrain

[How do I make this blob. I'm kind of confused on how to make the mesh rise up like that when I click the mouse button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpPS8.png)

[image]

Here is my mesh code. Its not too important to read through it. I just want to know how I get the blob by rising the the mesh:

```
{
    QuadMesh qm;        // The new quad mesh to be returned
    qm.numVertices = 0;
    qm.vertices = NULL;
    qm.numQuads = 0;
    qm.quads = NULL;
    qm.numFacesDrawn = 0;

    qm.maxMeshSize = maxMeshSize < minMeshSize ? minMeshSize : maxMeshSize;
    CreateMemoryQM(&qm);

    // Set up default material used for the mesh
    qm.mat_ambient[0] = 0.0;
    qm.mat_ambient[1] = 0.0;
    qm.mat_ambient[2] = 0.0;
    qm.mat_ambient[3] = 1.0;
    qm.mat_specular[0] = 0.0;
    qm.mat_specular[1] = 0.0;
    qm.mat_specular[2] = 0.0;
    qm.mat_specular[3] = 1.0;
    qm.mat_diffuse[0] = 0.75;
    qm.mat_diffuse[1] = 0.5;
    qm.mat_diffuse[2] = 0.0;
    qm.mat_diffuse[3] = 1.0;
    qm.mat_shininess[0] = 0.0;

    return qm;
}

void SetMaterialQM(QuadMesh* qm, Vector3D ambient, Vector3D diffuse, Vector3D specular, double shininess)
{
    qm->mat_ambient[0] = ambient.x;
    qm->mat_ambient[1] = ambient.y;
    qm->mat_ambient[2] = ambient.z;
    qm->mat_ambient[3] = 1.0;
    qm->mat_specular[0] = specular.x;
    qm->mat_specular[1] = specular.y;
    qm->mat_specular[2] = specular.z;
    qm->mat_specular[3] = 1.0;
    qm->mat_diffuse[0] = diffuse.x;
    qm->mat_diffuse[1] = diffuse.y;
    qm->mat_diffuse[2] = diffuse.z;
    qm->mat_diffuse[3] = 1.0;
    qm->mat_shininess[0] = (float)shininess;
}

// Allocate dynamic arrays.
bool CreateMemoryQM(QuadMesh* qm)
{
    const int maxVertices = (qm->maxMeshSize + 1) * (qm->maxMeshSize + 1);
    qm->vertices = (MeshVertex *)malloc(sizeof(MeshVertex) * maxVertices);
    if (qm->vertices == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    const int maxQuads = qm->maxMeshSize * qm->maxMeshSize;
    qm->quads = (MeshQuad *)malloc(sizeof(MeshQuad) * maxQuads);
    if (qm->quads == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


// Fills the array of vertices and the array of quads.
bool InitMeshQM(QuadMesh* qm, int meshSize, Vector3D origin, double meshLength, double meshWidth, Vector3D dir1, Vector3D dir2)
{
    Vector3D o;
    double sf1, sf2; 

    Vector3D v1,v2;

    v1.x = dir1.x;
    v1.y = dir1.y;
    v1.z = dir1.z;

    sf1 = meshLength/meshSize;
    ScalarMul(&v1, (float)sf1, &v1);

    v2.x = dir2.x;
    v2.y = dir2.y;
    v2.z = dir2.z;
    sf2 = meshWidth/meshSize;
    ScalarMul(&v2, (float)sf2, &v2);

    Vector3D meshpt;

    // Build Vertices
    qm->numVertices=(meshSize+1)*(meshSize+1);
    int currentVertex = 0;

    // Starts at front left corner of mesh 
    Set(&o, origin.x,origin.y,origin.z);

    for(int i=0; i< meshSize+1; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j< meshSize+1; j++)
        {
            // compute vertex position along mesh row (along x direction)
            meshpt.x = o.x + j * v1.x;
            meshpt.y = o.y + j * v1.y;
            meshpt.z = o.z + j * v1.z;

            Set(&qm->vertices[currentVertex].position, meshpt.x,meshpt.y,meshpt.z);
            currentVertex++;
        }
        // go to next row in mesh (negative z direction)
        Add(&o, &v2, &o);
    }

    // Build Quad Polygons
    qm->numQuads=(meshSize)*(meshSize);
    int currentQuad=0;

    for (int j=0; j < meshSize; j++)
    {
        for (int k=0; k < meshSize; k++)
        {
            // Counterclockwise order
            qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[0]=&qm->vertices[j*    (meshSize+1)+k];
            qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[1]=&qm->vertices[j*    (meshSize+1)+k+1];
            qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[2]=&qm->vertices[(j+1)*(meshSize+1)+k+1];
            qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[3]=&qm->vertices[(j+1)*(meshSize+1)+k];
            currentQuad++;
        }
    }

    ComputeNormalsQM(qm);

    return true;
}

// Draw the mesh by drawing all quads.
void DrawMeshQM(QuadMesh* qm, int meshSize)
{
    int currentQuad=0;

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, qm->mat_ambient);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, qm->mat_specular);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, qm->mat_diffuse);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, qm->mat_shininess);

    for(int j=0; j < meshSize; j++)
    {
        for(int k=0; k < meshSize; k++)
        {
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);

            glNormal3f(qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[0]->normal.x,
                       qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[0]->normal.y,
                       qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[0]->normal.z);
            glVertex3f(qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[0]->position.x,
                       qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[0]->position.y,
                       qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[0]->position.z);

            glNormal3f(qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[1]->normal.x,
                       qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[1]->normal.y,
                       qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[1]->normal.z);           
            glVertex3f(qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[1]->position.x,
                       qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[1]->position.y,
                       qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[1]->position.z);

            glNormal3f(qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[2]->normal.x,
                       qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[2]->normal.y,
                       qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[2]->normal.z);           
            glVertex3f(qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[2]->position.x,
                       qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[2]->position.y,
                       qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[2]->position.z);

            glNormal3f(qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[3]->normal.x,
                       qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[3]->normal.y,
                       qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[3]->normal.z);           
            glVertex3f(qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[3]->position.x,
                       qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[3]->position.y,
                       qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[3]->position.z);

            glEnd();
            currentQuad++;
        }
    }
}

// Deallocate dynamic arrays.
void FreeMemoryQM(QuadMesh* qm)
{
    if (qm->vertices != NULL)
        free(qm->vertices);
    qm->vertices=NULL;
    qm->numVertices=0;

    if (qm->quads != NULL)
        free(qm->quads);
    qm->quads=NULL;
    qm->numQuads=0;
}

// Use cross-products to compute the normal vector at each vertex
void ComputeNormalsQM(QuadMesh* qm)
{
    int currentQuad=0;

    for(int j=0; j < qm->maxMeshSize; j++)
    {
        for(int k=0; k < qm->maxMeshSize; k++)
        {
            Vector3D n0, n1, n2, n3;
            Vector3D e0, e1, e2, e3;

            for (int i=0; i < 4; i++)
            { 
                LoadZero(&qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[i]->normal);
            }

            Subtract(&qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[1]->position, &qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[0]->position, &e0);
            Subtract(&qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[2]->position, &qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[1]->position, &e1);
            Subtract(&qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[3]->position, &qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[2]->position, &e2);
            Subtract(&qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[0]->position, &qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[3]->position, &e3);
            Normalize(&e0);
            Normalize(&e1);
            Normalize(&e2);
            Normalize(&e3);

            Vector3D w;    // Working vector;

            Negate(&e3, &w);
            CrossProduct(&e0, &w, &n0);
            Normalize(&n0);
            Add(&qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[0]->normal, &n0, &qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[0]->normal);

            Negate(&e0, &w);
            CrossProduct(&e1, &w, &n1);
            Normalize(&n1);
            Add(&qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[1]->normal, &n1, &qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[1]->normal);

            Negate(&e1, &w);
            CrossProduct(&e2, &w, &n2);
            Normalize(&n2);
            Add(&qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[2]->normal, &n2, &qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[2]->normal);

            Negate(&e2, &w);
            CrossProduct(&e3, &w, &n3);
            Normalize(&n3);
            Add(&qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[3]->normal, &n3, &qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[3]->normal);

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Normalize(&qm->quads[currentQuad].vertices[i]->normal);
            }

            currentQuad++;
        }
    }
}
```

It will not if you try it because its linked to a main.c file but its basically generating a paper thin mesh with a green shade.

Comment: I don't understand the question to be honest. You have got an OpenGL app that generates the heightmap and renders it as quads, right? And you want the functionality so that when you click at some spot a "blob" is being rendered there, right? If I were you, I would just raycast from the camera to the point, find the nearest vertices (let's say 5x5 grid, this should be easy, since it's a heightmap) and offset them according to some function (gaussian or whatever fits your use-case) along the normal. Note that for a high-quality "blob", your heightmap should be pretty highpoly (+ Gouraud shading)

Comment: Yes I was thinking to use gaussian function. But how i do implemen raycast and how do I select individual vertices to change the normal?